# Javascript/Typescript: How can I set one known property in a deep nested javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have the next object:

```
private obj: someclass[] = 
  [
      {
          id: 1,
          label: 'label 1',
          type: { name: 'checkbox' },
          options: [
              { id: 1, isChecked: false},
              { id: 2, isChecked: false}
          ]
      },
      {
          id: 2,
          label: 'label 2',
          type: { name: 'checkbox' },
          options: [
              { id: 3, isChecked: false},
              { id: 4, isChecked: false}
          ]
      }
  ]
```

All I want to do is set every property named "isChecked" to `false`

I can probably create a new empty array and with a foreach loop and indexes recreate the whole object but with that property set to false, but Im im guessing that this being a common operation it should be simplier right? I tried mapping but all I got was `undefined`, can someone please point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: You want `isChecked` to be false for everything? Yeah, you'd need to loop through the array, then loop over the `o.options` array and set each of those items to false one by one. If you just want to do this for one particular options `id` frequently, then it's still O(n). Consider rearranging your structure to be keyed by options `id` so you can do it in O(1) to flip a single `isChecked`. _I tried mapping but all I got was undefined_--could you share the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this for example (every `isChecked` property is set to `true`):

```js
let arr = [
      {
          id: 1,
          label: 'label 1',
          type: { name: 'checkbox' },
          options: [
              { id: 1, isChecked: false},
              { id: 2, isChecked: false}
          ]
      },
      {
          id: 2,
          label: 'label 2',
          type: { name: 'checkbox' },
          options: [
              { id: 3, isChecked: false},
              { id: 4, isChecked: false}
          ]
      }
  ];
  
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    item.options.every(x => x.isChecked = true);
  });
  
  console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Why `every()` instead of `forEach()`?  The point of `every()` is to short circuit if the fallback returns something falsy, and to return a value.  If you don’t want either of those things then `every()` is a weird choice.